# control flow of recyclerView in android

Tags: android-recyclerview

I'm unable to understand the control flow of the recycler view in android.
we make a call to the adapter class in **mainActivity.kt** but where are the function calls for the three overridden methods of adapter class.
because why and where they (**getItemCount()**,**onCreateViewHolder()**) return values

Comment: _Hi Kiran! Welcome to stackoverflow. I need you add some code in your question so that some of us can understand and help you to get answer of your question_

Comment: Hello Kiran, welcome to SO. First you should read about [how to create a minimum reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem; that being said, [here's](https://github.com/Gryzor/GridToShowAds) a simple repo with a simple RecyclerView you can look at and observe how each method works and what it does, you can even clone it/fork it and play with it all you want. In fact, you can keep it and use it ("at your own risk") in your projects. I wrote it to test something, but it's a _very simple_ recyclerview (in Grid, but easy to change).